# Excel - Sum First Value Of Non-Unique Adjacent Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

I have a table:

```
ColA  |  ColB
  1       1
  2       1
  2       1
  3       1
  4       1
  5       1
```

I would like to sum ColB only once where ColA = 2.

Essentially, I would like to sum the values of ColB as if the table looked like

```
ColA  |  ColB
  1       1
  2       1
  3       1
  4       1
  5       1
```

So the sum of ColB should be 5 not 6

Any ideas on how I can do this?

[This site](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/06/25/sum-only-if-unique-value-in-another-column-in-excel) got me close, but it doesn't add either of the ColB values for the rows where ColA = 2.

Comment: If we assume that `A2` = 1, `A3` = 2, and `A4` also = 2, what do you want to have happen if `B3` ≠ `B4`?  (Or are ***all*** the `B` values equal to 1?  If so, you’re talking about a count rather than a sum.)  Do you guarantee that the `A` values are sorted?

Comment: if column A has a duplicate, then the adjacent value in column B will be the same as the corresponding value to the duplicate column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use unique filter with a simple =SUM formula

1. Select your table (A1:B7)
2. Go to: Menu Bar » Data » Filter » Special Filter
3. Check *No duplicates* and *Copy to another location*
4. Choose a single cell somewhere right to your table as *Copy to* location and press OK
5. Insert a =SUM(E2:E6) formula below your new ColB values

   [image]

**Note:** This will only work if ColB values and corresponding ColA values are the same - like you said in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce column C, assuming first row is labels, this formula starts in row 2

=COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)

Copy down and do a Sumif on column B where column c = 1

=SUMIF(C:C,1,B:B)  or

=SUMIFS(B:B,C:C,1)

Answer (score 0):

This single formula should give the required result

`=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B6/COUNTIF(A1:A6,A1:A6))`